Finding basis for column space of a matrix using only its REF?
Given the REF for the matrix A =
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & -3 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
can we deduce a basis for the column space of A using just its REF form ? (like in this case)

Yes you can. Do you know the definition of the column space?

From this information alone?  Very obviously not.  Consider two far simpler examples.  $\begin{bmatrix}1\1\1\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}1\2\-2\0\end{bmatrix}$.  Both of these have a very obvious basis for their column spaces (namely themselves) and these column spaces are different and yet both have REF equal to $\begin{bmatrix}1\0\0\0\end{bmatrix}$

If you have both the REF and the original matrix, the columns in which pivots occur in the REF can tell you which columns of the original matrix can be used for a basis if desired... but you stated in your question that you only have the REF (and not the original matrix)

@CyclotomicField N.B. column space is not row space.

The answer to this question depends on whether or not you have the original matrix. If you do not have the original matrix there's nothing you can do as there are infinitely many matrices that are row equivalent.
If you're given a matrix and told to find the column space, you may perform Gaussian Elimination and stop when REF is achieved. In REF you can determine the pivot columns which will correspond to the basis of the column space of the original matrix.
For example, using your given matrix $A$
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & -3 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
We have pivots in columns 1 and 2. If we have access to our original matrix then a basis for the column space is the first and second columns of that matrix.

@JMoravitz you're absolutely correct, just edited my answer.

Also, for completeness sake and to be pedantic... there are also two trivial cases where we can know the column space without the original matrix.  The first is where we find the rank is zero at which point the empty basis works... and the other is where we find the rank is equal to the number of rows, at which point the full elementary basis works

thank you so much @JMoravitz
